# Display latest list at the top

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

i have scenario where upload .csv file and display the message/status using listview.

Here is the snippet of the code:

```
listView1.View = View.List;
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem (new[]{"CUID:" + strCuID + " is refunded successfully"}));
listView1.GridLines = true;
```

the output:

> 01293821921DE is refunded successfully //first 
>   0123821921DE is refunded successfully
>   01693821921DE is refunded successfully //latest

and i would like the latest result show up first. How can i get the expected result?

Comment: show the loop, how you add items

Comment: As with any list, `Add` will append to the end of the list. If you want to insert before all other items, call `Insert` instead. You should have seen that when you read the relevant documentation, which should have been the first thing you did when realising there was a question to be answered.

Comment: `for (i = list.count - 1; i > -1; i--)` { listview.Add(... list[i]...) }

Comment: @nur wahidah, if the answer posted below helped solve your problem, you may accept it by clicking on the tick sign beside it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*OP: i would like the latest result show up first. How can i get the expected result?*

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<string> ListTest = new List<string>();
    ListTest.Add("01293821921DE is refunded successfully");
    ListTest.Add("0123821921DE is refunded successfully");
    ListTest.Add("01693821921DE is refunded successfully");

    Console.WriteLine("\n List in Order \n");

    foreach(var item in ListTest)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n List in Reverse Order \n");

    for(int i = ListTest.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ListTest[i]);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

DEMO:

[dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L2HiyW)